# Count rows and columns in ranges of varying size

Tags: vba, excel, count

The following short program should cycle through all sheets within a workbook and compare the values in the cells from (C11:end) to the cell in column B for that row, and then repeat this for each row below it where there is data.

The code won't run due to an 'overflow' error, implying that the variable NumRows is too large for the integer type (I think?). However, whilst the NumRows and NumCols vary from sheet to sheet, there are always <100 in each case. Changing the type to 'Long' causes Excel to hang. I'm not sure why this is happening, C11 is always bounded on both its right and bottom side by data so the .End function shouldn't be generating massive numbers.

I'm very new to all this so if anyone could please explain or suggest edits I'd be very grateful.

```
Sub cond_format()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

ws.Activate

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim NumRows As Integer
Dim NumCols As Integer

NumRows = ws.Range("C11", ws.Range("C11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
NumCols = ws.Range("C11", ws.Range("C11").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To NumRows
            For j = 1 To NumCols

                If Cells(10 + i, 2 + j).Value >= (Cells(i + 10, 2).Value) * 1.2 Then
                        Cells(10 + i, 2 + j).Interior.Color = 10092492
                ElseIf Cells(10 + i, 2 + j).Value <= (Cells(i + 10, 2).Value) * 0.8 Then
                    Cells(10 + i, 2 + j).Interior.Color = 5263615
                End If

            Next
    Next
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried `Dim`-ing your variables as `long`?

Comment: Have you checked the content of `NumRows` and `NumCols`? Also, wouldn't that be a case for conditional formatting?

Comment: Do what @cybernetic.nomad suggests and move them outside the loop while you are editing them.

Comment: You're looping throug worksheets, and then using `Cells()` but you are **not** "anchoring" those `Cells()` to the worksheet. I suspect you want to add `ws.` before those. i.e. `If ws.Cells(10+i, 2+j).Value >= ...`  I also suggest changing the numrows and num cols to work "backward": `NumRows = ws.Range("C" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` // `NumCols = ws.Cells(1,columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: @BruceWayne - fwiw, there is a ws.Activate inside the loop.

Comment: IMO, put an `Application.StatusBar = "On " & i & " of " & NumRows` inside your loop so you can watch how slow/fast your iterations are.

Comment: To follow up on Cybernetic's comment: A variable of "Integer" type in VBA can not hold a number higher than 32767. Excel can use up to 1048576 rows, and 16384 columns. When using a variable to loop Rows it is recommended to use a Long type variable, for Columns you can use an Integer type variable. You can make them all Long type, but for lower RAM footprint you want to use the best type for the use it will have.

Comment: After looking at your code and testing it, I believe it is possible that a formula and/or conditional formatting is making NumRows on xlDown be a higher value than the section you are trying to format. Turn NumRows into a Long and do a MsgBox NumRows right after a value is given and see what the number is. If the number is more than 32767 then that's the issue.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and apologies for the delayed response - I've been on holiday.

@Jeeped I've tried moving the variable declarations outside of the loop and changing their type to long, but this just causes Excel to crash. There is no obvious reason to me why NumRows or NumCols is >32767... they should never be more than 100 per sheet, I can only imagine that for some reason they're holding the number of rows/columns in aggregate across the workbook or the .End function is counting all the way to the end of the sheet or something...

Comment: @dwirony Changing NumRows to 'Long' and putting in that status bar counter, the code causes excel to freeze still but it froze on cycle 77 of 1048566 so at least I could see that NumRows is indeed the problem

Comment: @BruceWayne I have no idea why the .End(xlDown) command wasn't stopping at the end of the data but your idea of counting upwards has got it working - thank you very much